# What does this Visual Studio (2013 professional) magnify glass icon mean?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

[image: Moving icon]

In the bottom of my Visual Studio there is a little icon (see image)

It is a moving magnify glass (I think it's a magnify glass, I'm sure it's moving)

It's moving all the time (it's moving, in a circle shape, and the background 'block' shape is growing larger and smaller), but there is no hover text, nor can I click it...

I'm afraid of moving icons when I don't know what they do.....

Anyone know what it means/does?

EDIT:

when I click on F5, it's shown besides the VS build icon:
[image: icon besides the VS build icon]

Comment: something is analyzing your files. have you any extension installed in VS?

Comment: Webessentials and Resharper (and DevExpress controls suite)

Comment: `I'm afraid of moving icons when I don't know what they do.....` That's exactly what I've felt with Visual Studio >o<

Comment: @Jehof for what is worth, one could make an extension that only shows the icon and never hides it, without doing absolutely anything else. `Something is analyzing your files` could be pretty much misleading

Comment: `I'm afraid of moving icons when I don't know what they do.....` If you are paranoic it doesn't mean that nobody is watching you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the predefined `SBAI_Find` icon in Visual Studio's Status Bar Animation Region. Any extension could be triggering it (or even Visual Studio itself). There's more information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsstatusbar.animation(v=vs.100).aspx

There's no way to tell what is triggering it by your question only. To find the culprit, I'd try disabling all extensions and enabling them one-by-one.

Notice it shows when using the standard `Find` in Visual Studio (if you want a lengthy operation to check it, use `Find In Files`)

Comment: In the past, I've worried about this happening in Visual Studio. I still find it a concern at work because this symbol can mean "we're going to slow your developing down", since it almost always symbolises disk access. If you're on a single drive machine, you could be in trouble when this is showing due to VS' disk bandwidth requirements being so high (always better to develop with two or more drives). I've used Microsoft's RegMon or ProcMon to see what process is causing disk access requests. It doesn't resolve things but it helped me detect that the older version of R# needed optimising.

Answer (score -1):

In Simple Words , It Is a Search Engine Build By VB.net To Find Content According To The User's Requirement Needed And The Section Selected 
**Note**: Different Section Will Lead To Different Search Result

Comment: No, it's not. This answer doesn't make any sense at all

Answer (score -2):

It simply means, it is trying to find and link all the files. You should not be too much bothered about it and it is not from any of the third party extension.

Comment: Uh, no, it doesn't mean that, and it could be from a third party extension

Comment: @Jcl Please enlight me, so as a Visual studio user, should he be bothered about?

Comment: If the icon stays there all the time, yes, there is something triggering it and not removing it. Visual Studio uses that icon when issuing `Find` and `Find in files` (not at all when linking), but it removes it after it's done. Any third party extension can trigger that icon to appear (as I explained in my answer) and forget removing it. Just with what the OP stated in the question, it's impossible to determine what is making the icon appear.